# Apex class called from a flow wont give me the option to pass a collection of records

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I have a flow setup to pass in a collection of opportunities to process and send back a collection of opportunities. In the flow I have queried the opps, assigned them to a record collection variable and check the "Available for Output" option. However when I used the apex action in the flow, there is no option to pass the collection variable to the apex class. I am trying to understaynd why I can't pass in my record collection variable.

[image]

```
public class FindOpportunities {
@InvocableMethod(label='Find Opportunities')
public static List<List<Opportunity>> findOpps(List<Opportunity> oppList) {
    List<Opportunity> invalidOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
    
    for (Opportunity opp : oppList) {
        if (opp.AccountId != null && opp.Account.Type != 'Customer' && opp.Account.Account_Status__c != 'Active') {
            invalidOpps.add(opp);
        }
    }
    
    List<List<Opportunity>> result = new List<List<Opportunity>>();
    result.add(invalidOpps);
    
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you try keeping input parameter as `List<List<Opportunity>> oppList` and see if helps? [Related](https://unhandledsunshine.com/2021/08/12/invocable-methods-how-to-send-data-between-flow-and-apex/#:~:text=The%20apex%20receives%20it%20as%20a%20List%20of%20Lists%20of%20type%20Opportunity.)

Answer (score 0):

As you want to pass record collection variable to apex class, you need to use `List<List<sObject>>` as flows are bulkified and this is expected behavior.

Found this [article](https://unhandledsunshine.com/2021/08/12/invocable-methods-how-to-send-data-between-flow-and-apex/) having more information
[image]